# converting completeable future

Tags: spring-boot, completable-future

I'm new on completeable-future field. Anyway I have this basic JPA application I want to use async call. But I don't want the service return into completable future.

This one works fine, but..

```
   @Async
    @Cacheable(value="distributors")
    public CompletableFuture<Iterable<Distributors>> getAllDistributorsAsyncCaching() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Iterable<Distributors> result = distributorsRepository.findAll();
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);



    }
```

What I want the function to return just the iterable:

```
   @Async
    @Cacheable(value="distributors")
    public Iterable<Distributors> getAllDistributorsAsyncCaching() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        Iterable<Distributors> result = distributorsRepository.findAll();
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);



    }
```

I have tried with completeablefuture.get() but the problem is it becomes slow, 
then I tried with completeablefuture.complete() it gives me complete(Iterable) in CompleteableFuture cannot be applied to ().

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can put @Async on your repository method :

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
    @Async
    @Query("select f from Foo f")
    CompletableFuture<List<Foo>> findAllFoos();
}
```

Then in your service you call it with :

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        CompletableFuture<List<Foo>> futureFoos = fooRepository.findAllFoos();
        List<Foo> foos = null;

        try {
            foos = futureFoos.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return foos;
    }
}
```

Here is my test (i use h2 in-memory database) :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FooTests {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setId(Long.valueOf(i));
            foo.setName("foo" + i);
            fooRepository.save(foo);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {        
        System.out.println(fooService.getFoos().size());
    }
}
```

You can put `@Cacheable` on service method (here is `getFoos`)

Comment: I tried this code, but somehow the test result shows it's not async. it's still blocking.

Comment: sorry, yes, i left ".get()" which is blocking, i will modify my code.